# how to add elements in nsmutable array at run time dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

i have an nsmutable array , so i want to show elements of array on tableview but when i

scroll tableview cells new elements should be added .

there is a confusion how can i add elements on run time when table view scrolled . ??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    tableList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"John",@"Dick",@"nihyan",@"alex",@"niv",nil];
    NSLog(@" arr count in Friends list   %i",tableList2.count);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: [tableList addOvject:@""]

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed confused :)

Lets separate the answer to 2 scenarios:

1. **You know all your table view data from the beginning**: You don't need to add them yourself, you just need to pass the table view the full array with all the data that you need in `CellForRowAtIndexPath` and the table view will reuse the cells and display the next line when the user scrolls.
2. **You need to add Items**: The simplest way will be to add the new data to the array:

   ```
   [tableList1 addObject:YourObject];
   ```

   And then call:

   ```
    [self.yourTableView reloadData];
   ```

You should know that there are ways to add a single row with out refreshing all the table.

You can learn more here : [UITableView Guide](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UITableView/)